# Как заставить пользователей в порядке очереди выполнять файл

Tags: php

Есть PHP файл.
В файле есть PHP скрипт.

В скрипте идут разного рода проверки и запросы к базе.

Нужно сделать так, что-бы если юзеры открыли этот файл практичесски синхронно, то они встали в очередь на выполнение этого скрипта.

Ибо будет каша полнешая твориться.

Представьте человек открыл эту страницу, далее выполнился запрос на извлечение из базы доступныхзаписей(записей с которыми никто не работает сейчас другой.)

Далее скрипт проверяет подходят ил лично нам  извлечённые записи.

Если подходят, то идёт апдейт запрос на занесение значения о том. что я сэтими записями работаюю, и теперь другие пользователи не смогут извлечь эти записи.

Теперь представьте, что почти синхронно 2 человека обратились к скрипту.

У каждого есть по 2 запроса и по одной проверке.

Идёт запрос от первого человека, ему приходят свободные записи, но почти в этот же момент идёт запрос на извлечение записей от второго человека, и тот тоже извлекает тоже самое. Дальше второй запрос идёт от первого человека, и тот заносит данные о том, что апись занята, и от второго тоже идёт второй запрос и он тоже удачно обновил запись.

Такого быть не должно, нужно чтоб файлы обрабатывались у людей по очереди, понимаете?

Comment: Молчат все( Подскажите хотяб в какую сторону копать.

Comment: я не понял в чем вопрос, открывается php файл? очередь чего сформировать?

Comment: Есть файл в котором много запросов и проверок. Есть 1000 людей. Нужно чтоб этот файл выполнялся у них по очереди, но не вместе. Тобишь должна пройти цепочка запросов. цепочка проверок, любые операции в файле. и только когда файл завершится, только тогда второй человек смжет его выполнять. Я тогда не знаю как ещё объяснить. Вы не поняли?

Comment: Если 2 человека одновременно открыли файл, то сначала должен он выполниться у одного, а у второго должно быть ожидание, и только как у первого файл выполнится, только потом у второго файл начинает выполняться. Вроде понятно написал.

Comment: @MrCoder а БД тогда причем? Или вы БД называете файлом?

Comment: Не называю я ничего. Просто в файле есть скрипт. в котором идут разного рода проверки и запросы к базе. да что тут непонятного то??? Я хочу чтоб скрипт выполнился весь у человека, и только тогда он стал доступен другому.

Comment: @MrCoder Простите, но вы так изъясняетесь ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Как? Я нормально всё объямнил, вопрос ещё дополнил.

Comment: ЩАс опять перепишу

Comment: =( отредактировал.

Comment: Ну конфликты же будут, если скрипт выполняется почти синхронно у пользователей.  Как ещё объяснить не знаю.

Comment: Ответьте кто-небудь если до сех пор не понятно

Comment: ответьте кто небудь!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Используйте метод "симофоров" например

Answer (score 4):

Из пушки по воробьям: попробуйте организовать **очередь задач**.

При обращении пользователь не мгновенно получает ответ, а ставит своё задание в очередь, и получает уникальный id своей задачи. И начинает, напр., раз в секунду, осведомляться о состоянии выполнения своей задачи по её id - JS клиента может ajax'ом поллить раз в секунду, напр.

Выполняются задачи всего одним «рабочим» процессом, в порядке поступления. Такой процесс постоянно работает в фоне, ожидая поступления новых заданий.

Для организации очередей посмотрите на [Gearman](http://gearman.org/), RabbitMQ.

---

В вашей задаче, может, удастся ограничиться правильной работой с БД: [транзакциями](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html), если можно определить пригодность нужных записей не в php, а прямо в MySQL; или lock'ом таблиц в пределах времени работы одного php скрипта?

Answer (score 2):

Ваша проблема называется Race Condition в MySQL.
Можно залочить таблицу, использовать транзакции, выполнить всю работу за один запрос.

Похожие вопросы:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561241/how-to-avoid-race-condition-in-mysql
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364273/how-to-make-sure-there-is-no-race-condition-in-mysql-database-when-incrementing
- http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/LOCK_TABLES.html

Comment: Я Вас не понимаю.

Comment: @MrCoder изменил ответ

Comment: Ссылки на англоязычные обсуждения могут не всем быть полезны. Приведите, пожалуйста, в своём ответе общий смысл или подробное описание решений, на которые ссылаетесь.